# A modern replacement for GTK calls while using Python 3.6 on win7 Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pycairo

I'm exploring a [pyCairo tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gfx/pycairo/backends/).  Almost all the demonstration code relies on `from gi.repository import Gtk`.  I'm using `python 3.6` from an anaconda distribution on my win7 machine.  As far as I can see, this is not a supported package.   I dig up a lot of 5+ year old forum messages about installing it,  but everything looks messy and not up to the times.  I don't want to use an ancient python, either, because I love my f-strings.

Is there a recommended windowing system to use instead for modern python on anaconda that should use instead?  Is there a more contemporary version of GTK I could install instead? All these references I'm searching seem very dated.